# I can't use the color value to set the background for the layout

Tags: android, layout, colors, background

this is my layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/c8"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context="com.leo.accelerate.activity.SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="146dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/icon_splash"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/boost_shanping_name"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I got the error:

```
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.leo.accelerate:style/RtlOverlay.DialogWindowTitle.AppCompat" (7f0b0028)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0b0028 a=-1 r=0x7f0b0028}
```

I found the problem color according to the address value `0x7f0b0028`

```
 find . -type f | xargs grep "0x7f0b0028"

result:
./app-default-release/res/values/public.xml:    <public type="color" name="c8" id="0x7f0b0028" />
./app-default-release/smali/com/leo/accelerate/R$color.smali:.field public static final c8:I = 0x7f0b0028
```

The problem code is the `color` value named `c8` , It is used in the backgroud property in the layout

When I replace him with a drawable, the problem does not exist.

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: It would be good if you also provide color resource file code.

Comment: please let us know which answer helped you and if it solved your problem sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work just fine, the only reasons I know of that might cause a problem are:

1. the name of the color attribute you provided is incorrect.
2. the value which you gave the attribute in your color value folder is
   not supported.
3. you wrote the background attribute more than one time in the xml item
   you're trying to draw.
4. the emulator you're using does not support this color.

Please make sure to check all of those reasons, if after making sure all of those 4 you still have a problem, contact us and we will try to further investigate your problem.

Best Regards, Lidor

Comment: Please let us know which solution worked for you sir.

Comment: It seems that Android can't parse my definition in color.xml. When I use the color value pointed to by c8 as the background, it works fine.  There is no syntax error in my color.xml, because when I copy it into a brand new project, it works fine with @color/c8, I am confused

Comment: please add to your question your color.xml files, and any other file that associated with your layout here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your color value **@color/c8**. Your color **c8** value may be wrong. Try with another color, it is work. Try with **android:background="@android:color/black"**. If it is working then I'm sure that your color value is wrong. You can not use hex color value like **0x7f0b0028**.